# Working effectivly with HTML in embeed web-server inside a .net/wpf-app

Tags: .net, html, wpf, dom

I have a pretty complex composite application (.NET/WPF/Prism). It runs on some kind of embedded devices (with full fledge window 7), let's call them "kiosks". I need to allow remote control for the applicaton. i.e. it should have an embedded web-server which will provide some information via http/html for remote control (checking status, logs, etc).

So in some application's module I need to compose HTML to return it. This seems to be pretty tedious. It looks like:

```
using (Stream ostr = ...)
using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(ostr))
{
    tw.WriteLine("<html>");
    tw.WriteLine("<head>");
    tw.WriteLine("<title>Web Console</title>");
    tw.WriteLine("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"2\" />");
}
```

I want to simplify HTML creation process. So I'm looking for some kind of .NET HTML DOM library. And can't find decent one. Only one I've found so far - [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com). It looks cool but I believe it targets a bit other use-case (load some HTML and search with xpath/linq). But I need just compose HTML, not parse, not query. 
I'd expect from a library API similar to System.Xml.Linq.

Something like this:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.Head.AddScript(ScriptLanguages.JavaScript, "http://localhost/scripts/jquery.js");
htmlDoc.Body.Elements(
  new HtmlDiv {
    Style="align:center", 
    Content = new []{new TextBlock("Hi")} }, 
  new HtmlDiv (
    new HtmlLabel(text: "StartDate", nameFor: "dtStartDate"),
    new HtmlTextBox(clintName: "dtStartDate", style: "width:100px")
  )
);
```

Another posibility that comes to my mind is to use some kind of templating engine. But I have no idea which one will work seamessly with embedded web-server.

I'm open for you thoughts, thanks in advance.

p.s. If you wonder "Embedded web-server" is http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/CSharpEmbeddedHTTPServer.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about you, but the HTML seems simpler to write read and understand. What benefit are you expecting by generating html in the way you suggested?

As to a template engine, you can easily create one yourself. Create an html page (one or more) with the theme you want. Add tags like %%title%% %%content%%, load the file do a regexp replacement, then serve the html. Wrap it up in a class and you have a very simple, flexible and easy to maintain solution.

Comment: +1 Yep, just ship with your app the templated HTML views and do replace at run time. Seems simple enough.

Comment: I think, working with text generation seems simple only at the beggining. I'm going to generate not static HTML (yeah, didn't mention that). It'll be driven by data. If it was a server app I'd use asp.net mvc. Can you imagine working with plain text in an aspnet-like backend app? I can't.